# In Tailwindcss, how do I set a margin for the smallest screen only, and leave the rest screen sizes untouched

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

In my specific case i want

```
<div className="mx-auto"...</div>
```

but only if the screen is the smallest.
Doing:

```
<div className="sm:mx-auto"...</div>
```

will have the opposite affect (of setting margin to auto for small screens and up).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Tailwind 3.2 you can use `max-sm:mx-auto` to achieve what you want.
[More info can be found here.](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/tailwindcss-v3-2#max-width-and-dynamic-breakpoints)